# Would it be appropriate to point out an error in another paper during a referee report?

Tags: peer-review

I just finished refereeing a paper in math. The paper was completely incorrect and unsalvageable. The authors (very senior) made a trivial mistake (confusing two definitions), and the rest of the paper was simply incorrect. I wrote a long and constructive report with some literature to review.

Out of curiosity, I checked some of their other papers. There was another preprint on the same topic, and they made the same, fatal mistake. I was thinking of pointing this out in the report, hoping I would be helpful, but I was not sure if this was appropriate. I decided not to, to be on the safe side.

Would this have been appropriate? The paper would be rejected regardless, but I didn't want the authors to think I had a personal vendetta against them — I wrote a long report trying to be helpful.

Comment: Whether or not you mentioned it in the report, it's perfectly appropriate to comment on the preprint itself with the problem.

Comment: @JackAidley How would I do this? It's just on arXiv. I would prefer to not email them, at least with my institutional email.

Comment: I am curious. What are these two definitions that were confused?

Comment: What would you have done if the review process was double-blind and you would not know they are the preprint authors?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you're writing a review *for the current paper*, not another one. A review is an aid for an editor to make a decision, and for authors to improve the paper, and so talking about anything other than the current paper is in some sense a waste of space and everyone's mental capacity.

That said, I do not think that it is *inappropriate*. As an author, assuming that the mistakes are honest ones, I might appreciate if someone added an appendix to a review in which they stated that in the process of reviewing, they also took a look at another one of my papers and found that it contained the same mistake. That's particularly true if that other paper is still a preprint I can fix.

Comment: More pragmatically, this also forestalls the situation where the authors/reviewers say "But see the proof in [other flawed paper]."

Comment: @Matt which would inevitably lead to [citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/)

Comment: It depends... If the paper you're reviewing relies upon the assumption that the other paper is correct, but it isn't, that has a direct impact on the one you're reviewing

Answer (score 8):

What you suggest is appropriate, constructive, and sometimes even necessary!  It is important for the scientific community to do its best to maintain the accuracy of the research literature, and pointing out errors in the kind of situation you describe serves to advance thus purpose.  I have certainly done this kind of thing, making authors aware of related errors in their other papers.

This issue can crop up in a couple slightly different ways.  In the situation described in question, it seems like an error has infiltrated the authors' work, and it has affected more than one paper, but the papers do not depend upon one-another directly.  In this case—especially if none of the work has been officially published—letting the authors know that their problem is more general and not just restricted to the specific manuscript you are reviewing gives them a chance to fix things.  Most of the time, I think authors have taken this type of criticism in stride and made appropriate changes to all of their affected papers.

However, the situation can be a little trickier when the errors occur in works that that are not parallel, but rather sequential.  In one case like this, a manuscript I was refereeing specifically relied on a result from another paper by (some of) the same group of authors.  That paper had already been refereed and (erroneously) published, but some of its main results were incorrect (or at least, incorrectly derived).  In order to explain why the manuscript I was looking at was in need of major revisions, I had to explain that the method used in the earlier paper (and incidentally, as I point out, a number of other unpublished preprints by this group of authors).  In addition to laying this out in my report for the authors, I explained the situation in quite a bit of detail in my confidential report to the editor.

Comment: +1 for ... *appropriate, constructive, and sometimes even necessary* ... and for ... *important for the scientific community to do its best to maintain the accuracy of the research* ... *I explained the situation*

Answer (score 1):

They are very seniors, so a rejected paper will be just a +1 in their list of rejected papers, they will not take offense for that.

Additionally, since they have a preprint on arXiv, it may not be completely off to publicly write a commentary to the preprint in arXiv directly (you may ask them if they agree).